# Java String Split Method Error?

Tags: java, split

Why does `(("+k").split("k"))[0]` not equal `"+"`? I am so confused.

Program:

```
//The Control Test
String a = "+";
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println((byte) a.charAt(0));
System.out.println(a == "+");

//The Error
a = (("+k").split("k"))[0];
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println((byte) a.charAt(0));
System.out.println(a == "+");
```

Output:

```
+
43
true
+
43
false  -- Why?
```

So why in the world does a "+" not equal a "+"?!

Comment: Checkout .compareTo and .equals on the String class

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't compare Strings with `==`. You should compare them with `.equals()` instead.

```
if(a.equals("+"))
{
    // ...
}
```

This person explained it very well so there is no need for me to explain it again: look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/2221461) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

String literals (strings placed directly in code) are stored in String pool and if some string literal is used few times same object from String pool is used. Since `==` compares references it will return `true` for

```
String a = "+";
System.out.println(a == "+");
```

Now Strings that are results of methods are separate objects that are not placed in String pool so in

```
String a = (("+k").split("k"))[0];
```

String object stored in `a` is different then `"+"` from String pool that is why `==` returns false.

To get rid of this problem you need to use `equals` method which will compare characters stored in String objects.